# How can I resize a circle when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and have figured out how to resize all circles when I click on any one of them. However, what I want is to only resize the circle that was clicked. The remaining circles should stay the same. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<g id="bubble-nodes">
    <rect id="bubble-background"></rect>
    <a class="class="bubble-node">
        <circle r="65"></circle>
    </a>
    ....
</g>
```

Javascript/D3:

```
// this works. It allows me to resize all circles when I click on one of them.
// but, it's not what I want
var resizeCircle = function () {
    var circle = d3.selectAll('circle');
    circle.attr("r", 85);
};

// this is what I want, but it doesn't work. 
// I want to resize the circle I clicked on
var circle = d3
    .selectAll('circle')
    .on("click", function (d) {
        return d.attr("r", 85);
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I could help you with JS/CSS, but I know nothing about D3.

Comment: Is there a point to using the HTML code like that? You can construct the entire circle within D3. That way you are streamlining everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
var circle = d3
    .selectAll('circle')
    .on('click', function (d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("r", 85);
    });
```

Comment: You'll want to use the `mousedown` event, and then bind another callback to `mouseup` to put it back to 65.

Comment: Very nice to use a scalar instead of a static number. 

ex: .on("click", function (d) { d3.select(this).attr("r", d.r * 3); });

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Any ideas on how I can change the radius our a circle without clicking on it? For example, can I click on ``<div>click me</div>`` and have it change the radius of a particular circle.